# Equivalent conditions for local martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, local-martingales

I am having some trouble solving this task:

> Consider the solution $X$ of the
>   SDE in $\mathbb{R}^n$
>   $$\mathrm{d} X_t = b (X_t) \mathrm{d} t + \sigma (X_t) \mathrm{d} B_t,$$
>   where $B$ is a $n$-dimensional Brownian motion and 
>   $b : \mathbb{R}^n_{} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, 
>   $\sigma : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ 
>   locally bounded coefficients.
>
> Let $a (x) = \sigma (x) \sigma(x)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and for all $f \in C^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$
>   let $$\mathcal{L}f (x) = b (x) \cdot \nabla f (x) + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr} [a(x) \nabla^2 f (x)], \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
>   where $\nabla^2 f (x)$ is the $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ matrix of second
>   derivatives of $f$.
>   Prove that the following conditions are equivalent
>
> > i) For any $f \in C^2 (\mathbb{R}^d)$, the process $M^f_t = f (X_t) -
> > f (X_0) - \int_0^t \mathcal{L}f (X_s) \mathrm{d} s$ is a local martingale.
> >
> > ii) For any $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the process $M^v_t = v \cdot X_t - v
> > \cdot X_0 - \int_0^t v \cdot b (X_s) \mathrm{d} s$ is a local martingale
> >     with quadratic variation
> >     $$ [M^v]_t = \int_0^t v \cdot a (X_s) v \mathrm{d} s. $$
> >
> > iii) For any $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the process
> >     $$Z^v_t = \exp \left( M^v_t - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t v \cdot a (X_s) v
> > \mathrm{d} s \right)$$
> >     is a local martingale.
>
> ***Hint: use the fact that linear combinations of exponentials are
>   dense in $C^2$ w.r.t. uniform convergence on compacts for the functions
>   and its first two derivatives (assumed wihtout proof)***

"$i)\Rightarrow ii)$":
Consider $f(X_t)=v\cdot X_t$.
Then $f$ is $C^2$ with $\nabla f=v$ and $\nabla^2 f=0$, thus we have
$$M_t^f=v\cdot X_t-v\cdot X_0-\int_0^t v\cdot b(X_s)\mathrm{d} s=M_t^v$$
Now by assumption $M_t^f=M_t^v$ is a local martingale.
Furthermore
$$M^v_t=v\cdot X_t-v\cdot X_0-\int_0^t v\cdot(\mathrm{d} X_s-\sigma(X_s)\mathrm{d} B_s)
=-v\cdot X_0-\int_0^t v\cdot\sigma(X_s)\mathrm{d} B_s.$$
This is an Ito process, so the quadratic variation is given by
$$[M^v]_t
=\int_0^t(v\cdot\sigma(X_s))(v\cdot\sigma(X_s))^T\mathrm{d} s
=\int_0^t v\cdot\sigma(X_s)\sigma(X_s)^T v\mathrm{d} s
=\int_0^t v\cdot a(X_s)v\,\mathrm{d} s.
$$
"$ii)\Rightarrow iii)$":
I know that
$$Z^v_t=\exp\left( M^v_t-\frac{1}{2}[M^v]_t \right),$$
which looks familiar, but I have to confess that I have only taken an introductory course in probability so far and starting pretty much from scratch in terms of martingales and stochastic processes.

"$iii)\Rightarrow i)$":
By the hint, $f$ can be approximated by linear combinations of exponentials, e.g. there
exists a sequence of functions $f_k(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n_k-1}\lambda_{i_k}\exp(t_{i_k}|x|)$ such that
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in K}
|f(x)-f_k(x)|+|f'(x)-f_k'(x)|+|f''(x)-f_k''(x)|=0$$
for all compact sets $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$...

I don't know how to get from the assumption in iii) and the approximation to the conclusion that $f$ is a local martingale.
How do I get my $Z^v_t$ in there?
I suspect I have to choose the $v$ accordingly to have $f_k$ in the form of $f_k(X_t)=\sum_i\lambda_i Z^v_t$?